# Show uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I hope anyone can help with this!

Assume that

$f(x) \rightarrow a$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$

$f(x) \rightarrow b$ for $x \rightarrow -\infty$.

I've already shown that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $M>0$ such that  $|f(x)−f(y)|<\epsilon$ as long as $x,y>M$ and now I have to show that $f$ is uniformly continuous but I don't know how and would appreciate some inputs.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are these all the information about $f$?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh The only things I know besides this are that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Hint: $f$ converges to a finite limit for $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$. Therefor you can apply a triangle inequality and $\epsilon/2$ argument for the tails. Then use the hint provided in the answer by Patrick.

Comment: @jdods Thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: Please add the information that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb {R} $ in the question body also.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:f is continous on [-2M,2M], which is a compact se so is uniformly continous.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it